# Phpmyadmin sql import error, Joomla 2.5

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, joomla2.5, cpanel

I'm receiving this error #1064 when i try to import the sql i recently exported. This is within phpmyadmin. Joomla site exists on host but the domain expired, I now need to apply a new domain different to the first. No access to Joomla right now. Using cpanel. Help greatly appreciated, no expert here. Please see attached screengrab.

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XmQP.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a minus `-` before `CREATE TABLE`. Remove that and it'll work fine

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Sjon, I tried what you suggeted however received this result  http://i.imgur.com/jtNn3cy.png

Comment: Create a database first, and import the dump in there

Comment: Ok So I've added a new database and tried to import again, this is the error screen http://i.imgur.com/UIbUaMv.png Thanks

Comment: Your server not support Innodb motor. See on your machine ( cat /etc/my.cnf | grep skip-inndob. If exist comment and restart mysql. ) If you are not root of machine ask your hosting provider.

Comment: @DoeJolan Don't know where you got that dump from, but `TYPE=InnoDB` should be replaced with `ENGINE=InnoDB`

Comment: Thanks guys, I have changed TYPE to ENGINE. I then

Comment: new database created

re-imported sql export with new domain changes 

error received after a few minutes:
Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume.

Comment: After I resubmit the file I get #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'